# Genymotion on VMWare

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vmware, dhcp, genymotion

I'm on Xubuntu running with VMWare on Windows 7. I'm developing an android app' and use genymotion to run virtual android device. But from few days, when I try to run my virtual device genymotion show me this error :

(translated from French)

> Impossible to run the Genymotion virtual terminal.
>
> The Genymotion virtual terminal haven't obtained IP address.
>
> For an unknown reason, the VirtualBox's DHCP server haven't assigned IP address to the virtual terminal. Please run VirtualBox to find a solution for the issue.
>
> For further help, please go to :
> https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-nostart

So, I followed the link and see that I should have the same IP address for the adapter and the DHCP server and explain how to modify. I change the IP of the DHCP server to be the same as the adapter. But looks like it doesn't fix the issue because the same message appear after the modification.

A friend of mine told me to download the latest version of Genymotion. I did but there's still the same issue.

For the reason why I'm on such virtual device is because I had lot of problem have a stable installation with dual boot windows/linux so I choose a virtualisation of linux instead. And I can't work on windows because it's a team work and work on windows have some conflict with work on linux.

I hope I've been understandable and excuse me for the language fault.

EDIT :

I've try creating a new virtualisation of Xubuntu and install genymotion to see if it was an update I mad or an other mistake I could have done that broke genymotion.
But the same problem appear. I think the problem come from the double virtualisation but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I just found what my problem was (or look's like). In the settings of the virtual device, in the CD/DVD (SATA) section I choose "use ISO image file" instead of "use physical drive".

I don't know why the issue was related with the CD/DVD. But now I can run the genymotion virtual device. It's slow as hell but it work.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a way to run Android Emulator on MAC (running with VMWare on Windows):

First  open VirtualBox and start your Android device. Then start the same device in Genymotion.

To have a relative smooth reaction time - set video memory to 128MB and Motherboard memory to 1024MB in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do virtualisation from a virtualized guest.
You must install Genymotion on the host OS.

You can see an entry on this subject on the Genymotion FAQ here: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#genymotion-from-virtualized-host

Answer (score 0):

To run the android apps on genymotion or your device from vm, you can follow these instructions:

1. Install genymotion on your local os
2. Install arm translation app on your genymotion
3. Reboot genymotion
4. Install google play service on genymotion
5. Reboot again
6. Download & install adb wireless app from play store on genymotion
7. Run adb wireless then get allocated ip address that generated by
   this app
8. Run this command on vm

`adb connect <IpAddressGeneratedByAdbWireless>`

enjoy!